# WPF Tabcontrol : Find number of rows created to show all tab headers

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I have a dialog which shows a tab control, I have all the logic in place to figure out the largest tabitem it then this size is used to resize my dialog. It all works fine if I have a single row of tab items, if multiple rows get created then i am not able to calculate the height properly because I dont know how many rows of tabs were created.

How can I find out the number of rows that were created to render all tabs?

Update:

`SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;` works when I want the dialog to autosize, now I also want to have a fixed size dialog, here, I want to override the size of my tabitem content to be (dialog height - buttons below the tabcontrol - number of tabrows * tab row height), so the question still stands.

Also, `SizeToContent` leaves a single line at the bottom of my dialog, which disappears when you try to resize the dialog, I tried invalidating the visual, but it does not help, any ideas?

Comment: You dont need to calculate anything, Just set the `Window` to `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` and it will size to your `Dialog` automaticly to fit your `TabControl`

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Thanks, SizeToContent does work, but now I am thinking of having a fixed dialog too, in which case I will need to know the number of tab rows

Comment: You could set `ResizeMode="NoResize"` and set the `Min/MaxHeight` and `Min/MaxWidth` to create the fixed dialog size, as I dont think you are going to find a nice way to calculate the size of the tabcontro. One option could be use the `TabControls` `Loaded` event and inside set the Dialogs `Width/Height` to the `TabControls` `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties these will return the rendered size of the tabcontrol.